# I am using ionic framework and want to use cordova themeablebrowser to open few urls inside the app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

But I am not able to show the close images and hence not able to perform close action. Can someone please help me with where exactly should my close images be?

Here is my code:

```
cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open(url, '_blank', {
          statusbar: {
              color: '#ffffff'
          },
          toolbar: {
              height: 44,
              color: '#56ad9b'
          },
          title: {
              color: '#ffffff',
              showPageTitle: true
          },
          "browserProgress": {
            "showProgress": true,
            "progressBgColor": "#016585",
            "progressColor": "#FFAA16"
          },
          closeButton: {
              image: 'close.png',
              imagePressed: 'close_pressed.png',
              align: 'left',
              event: 'closePressed'
          },
          backButtonCanClose: true
        }).addEventListener('backPressed', function(e) {
            alert('back pressed');
        }).addEventListener(cordova.ThemeableBrowser.EVT_ERR, function(e) {
            console.error(e.message);
        }).addEventListener(cordova.ThemeableBrowser.EVT_WRN, function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "Import Native Images" section in readme file.

https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser/blob/master/README.md#import-native-images

For android images should be inside "res" folder and for iOS it should be inside "Resource" folder.
And you do not need to add file extension in your code.